# Paging and Sorting in Mutliple Partial View with MVC Contrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, paging, mvccontrib

I create an application using asp mvc razor + mvc grid.
My problem is : i have one view that contain multiple action that return partial view, in each partial view there is a grid that display the data. I am using mvc contrib grid which support paging and sorting.

My view (index.cshtml) :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="formations" class="control-group">
    @Html.Action("Formations")
</div>

<div id="pools" class="control-group">
    @Html.Action("Pools")
</div>

<div id="zones" class="control-group">
    @Html.Action("Zones")
</div>
```

Formations action :

```
    public ActionResult Formations(GridSortOptions sort, int? page, string filter = "all")
    {

        IPagination<StratUnitVo> pagination = ....        
        return PartialView("_Formations", pagination);
    }
```

Partial View _Formations :

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Sort(ViewData["sort"] as GridSortOptions).Columns(col =>
  {
       col.For(p => Html.ActionLink(p.LongName, "EditFormation", "Stratigraphy", new { id = p.Id }, null).ToHtmlString()).Encode(false).Named(Locale.Name).SortColumnName("LongName");
       col.For(p => p.FormCode).Named(Locale.Code);
   col.For(p => p.ReferenceStratUnit.LongName).Named(Locale.ReferenceFormation);      
   }).Attributes(@class => "table table-condensed table-striped table-hover")

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.Raw(@Html.Pager(Model)));
}
```

Other action and view is most like sample above (just difference in the model data).
My problem is :

1. When i click the navigation paging in one grid (example : Formations), the other grid (Pools and Zones) will be navigate to. For example : click page 2 in formations grid will move another grid to page 2 too.
2. When i click the column header in one grid (which mean i want to sort the data), the whole page is replaced by partial view. What i want is only the grid that i have clicked is sorted.

How can i fix that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I just solved my problem like this :

1. For paging : add new parameter for each action called 'type' and validate based on the parameter.

   ```
   public ActionResult Formations(GridSortOptions sort, int? page, string type, string filter = "all")
   {
       if (type != null && !type.Equals("Formation")) page = 1;            

       IPagination<StratUnitVo> pagination = ......
       return PartialView("_Formations", pagination);
   }
   ```
2. For sorting : use ajax sort for mvc  grid :

   ```
   $(function () {
       ajaxSort('pools', 'Stratigraphy', 'Pools');
       ajaxSort('formations', 'Stratigraphy', 'Formations');
       ajaxSort('zones', 'Stratigraphy', 'Zones');         
   });

   function ajaxSort(tableId, controllerName, actionName) {
   $(document).on('click', '#' + tableId + ' > table > thead > tr > th > a', (function () {
   // store the href attribute, will get the column and direction parameter
   var href = $(this).attr('href');

   // mvc grid sort url is : 'http\\controllerName\\actionName?Column=columnname&Direction=[Ascending|Descending]            
   var temp = href.split('&');

   // retrieve the column name
   var column = temp[0].split('=')[1];
   // retrieve sort direction
   var direction = temp[1].split('=')[1];
   // retrieve column header
   var columnHeader = $(this).text();

   // remove the href attribute, prevent postback
   $(this).removeAttr('href');

   // use ajax to sort
   $.ajax({
       url: '/' + controllerName + '/' + actionName,
       data: { 'Column': column, 'Direction': direction },
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function (data) {                
           $('#' + tableId).html(data);

           columnHeader = columnHeader.replace('\u25B2', '').replace('\u25BC', '');

           // show up down arrow
           // \u25B2 and \u+25BC is the unicode character for up/down triangle (arrow) to display in HTML                                
           var column = $('#' + tableId + ' > table > thead > tr > th > a:contains(' + columnHeader + ')');

           if(direction == 'Ascending')
               column.text(columnHeader + "\u25B2");
           else {                
               column.text(columnHeader + "\u25BC");
           }
       },
      });
     }));
   }
   ```